# Python: MySQLdb confuse with the query

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to query a table from MySQL
In MySQL
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Item LIKE 'G%'` able to query data but `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Item LIKE G%` not result error 1064
In Python

```
query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Item LIKE %s%% "
data = 'G'
cur.execute(query%(data))
```

It return error but it works if

```
query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Item LIKE '%s%%' "
```

is using `'%s'` instead of `%s` is the correct way?
what about for float and integer? If data is integer, shall I put `int(data`) or `float(data)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct your like expression beforehand and *parameterize the query*:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Item LIKE %s"
data = 'G'
cur.execute(query, (data + "%", ))
```

Comment: If I have multiple data input? cur.excecute(query,(data1+"%",data2+"%")?

Comment: @bkcollection exactly, put them into a tuple in the second argument to execute.

Comment: do you mean 'data=(data1,data2), and then tuple(data)?

Comment: @bkcollection if a query is for example: `"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Item LIKE %s AND Item2 LIKE %s"`, then you can parameterize it like: `cur.execute(query, (data1 + "%", data2 + "%"))`. Hope it works for you.

Comment: ,Thanks. Is `query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Item LIKE '%s'"` is a correct way to query from database?

Comment: @bkcollection if you are parameterizing a query, you don't need the single quotes around the placeholder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132306/discussion-between-bkcollection-and-alecxe).

Answer (score 0):

A much more pythonic way could be using `format`:

```
sql_template = 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Item LIKE {}'
sql_template.format('G%') # 'SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Item LIKE G%'
```

Give it a try.

Comment: May be pythonic, but much more dangerous to string-format the query comparing to parameterizing.

Comment: Be 100% sure that G% is not a variable containing raw user input. If so this may be vulnerable to sql injection. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection . @alecxe did mention that it was dangerous, I just wanted to clarify why.